# Using Matlab Enumerations

Tags: matlab

Here is an edge case I've discovered to using Matlab enumerations.  I'm converting some old code that used string inside a class to fulfill the functions of an enumeration to a proper enumeration.  Now, as I convert that code I have many examples of this:

```
output = [enumVariable ' plus some text'];
```

(where `enumVariable` is of type `myEnum`): as I build up strings for errors, etc.  However, since the enumerated variable is first, Matlab is trying to convert the resultant string into the `myEnum` type, giving me an error:

```
Cannot convert an object of class 'char' to enumeration class 'myEnum' because there is no conversion method available.
```

Is there some easy to get around this, or do I have to go change every usage?

- I thought about redefining the "char()" function for myEnum, but that's not it - I don't want to end up with a frequency object.
- I certainly could replace every use of `[enumVariable` with `[char(enumVariable)` - but I'm trying to avoid that work.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error message you get. Please add a complete example to reproduce the problem into the question.

Comment: Okay, I got it, the specific error message depends on the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of overloading methods was the right idea, you simply tried it with the wrong method. You have to overload `horzcat`. Instead of overloading just this method, I recommend to implement `vertcat` and `horzcat` using `cat` and only reimplement this more generic method.

```
classdef myEnum
   enumeration
      Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
   end
   methods
       function c=cat(obj,d,varargin)
           if isa(varargin{1},class(obj)) %do not cast
               c=builtin('cat',d,obj,varargin{:});
           else %builtin cast
               obj2=cast(obj,class(varargin{1}));
               c=builtin('cat',d,obj2,varargin{:});
           end
       end
       function c=horzcat(obj,varargin)
           c=obj.cat(2,varargin{:});
       end
       function c=vertcat(obj,varargin)
           c=obj.cat(1,varargin{:});
       end

   end
end
```

a simple demonstration:

```
>> enumVariable=myEnum.Monday

enumVariable = 

    Monday   

>> [enumVariable ' plus some text']

ans =

Monday plus some text
```

Comment: The only problem it then I can't have arrays of this enum, but I can't think of a case where I'd want to, so nothing lost.  Thanks!!